# EEPROM only retaining a value for a short duration

Tags: embedded, eeprom

### Background

I have a product that includes an SPI EEPROM connected to a Microcontroller.

Address 0 if the EEPROM contains what we call the status word. In production the value of the status word is set to `0x2152` which indicates that the EEPROM is "alive" and the rest of the data stored in the EEPROM is sane.

If a erase/write/read/verify failure occurs we mark the status word as `0xDEAD`. We also mark the status word as `0xDEAD` if we detect corrupt data at boot. Note, `0xDEAD == ~0x2152`

### The Problem

I've noticed on small population of our units when I write a value of `0x2152` to the EEPROM's status word and read it back immediately it is still `0x2152`, but if I then perform a read several seconds later the value seems to "decay" to `0x2142` or `0x2102`. On a particular unit I read the value back five minutes later and it was `0x0000`. All of the other locations in the EEPROM can be written to and appear to retain the proper values for long periods of time.

We do not think we write/erase to that EEPROM location frequently, nominally just once ever. We have identified a situation though where we could perform a lot of writes/erases to that location in production if some steps are not performed correctly. The endurance is a million writes and we could be hitting that.

We perform frequent reads from this location over the life of the product, we generally read every give minutes.

### The Question

Previously in my career I've always seen write endurance failures look like sticking bits that seem to never take on a new value. Could this "decay" phenomenon that I am seeing also be a explained by excessive writes? Or is there another way EEPROM could become damaged that could explain this failure mode?

### EDIT:

Answers to questions in the comments, and some tangential things:

- I am deliberately not including the part number or data sheet because we have an open case with the vendor and I do not want to disclose too much if we end up uncovering a quality issue.
- The SPI clock speed is 1MHz.
- Writes are self timed by the part. We confirm the part is done with its write before attempting any other operations or powering it down (the part signals it is done on is MISO line)
- We're using a hardware SPI peripheral with software control of CS.
- This is a bare metal system.
- We have adequate delays on power up before attempting to communicate with the part.
- We always enable writes before writing.
- Interrupts are not factor, we do a blocking write in the main thread.
- The minimum erase/write block is one 16 bit word, this part is word addressable.
- This part has a erase/write endurance or 1M cycles per word.
- The power supply to the system is very stable, the system is powered by a lithium thionyl chloride battery that has tab welded leads. It is connected to the PCB with a robust connector that is potted over so vibration/contact bounce isn't possible. The system is "always on", the microcontroller is in control of when it goes to sleep.
- The voltage at the VCC pin of the EEPROM is stable and within spec throughout the duration of a write. This was measured with an o'scope.

Comment: EEPROM type and link to datasheet? What SPI mode and speed are used? I suppose you won't post the SPI code if I ask? On which MCU the code is running, do you use software SPI, hardware SPI? Software CS control or hardware? Multitasking OS or bare metal? Can interrupts corrupt the EEPROM usage? Does code wait for the EEPROM to be ready after write? Is the max block write size obeyed?

Comment: If it's ONLY that location you're having trouble with, seems you are probably right and it's getting written too much.   I'd put the SPI line on a scope and see if there's drastically more activity occuring that you think.

Comment: @justme I am deliberately not giving the part number or linking the datasheet. I have an open support ticket with the vendor and do not want to include their name in this in case it ends up being some sort of a quality issue.

Comment: BTW -- -  "0xDEAD".    Very funny   ;)    I might use that!

Comment: ALso - are you sure your write-voltage is high enough???    Many EEPROMS require something more than their standard 3.3 or 5V  VCC to ensure a good write.

Comment: >>> I am deliberately not giving the part number or linking the datasheet. I have an open support ticket with the vendor and do not want to include their name in this in case it ends up being some sort of a quality issue      ---------    I would bet a month of lunches that the problem is you, not the IC

Comment: @justme That's correct, I don't want to post any code. I am not sure how the SPI mode is relevant. I will answer your other questions in an edit.

Comment: @Nick I understand. It looks like you have been pretty thorough, so based on your edits, I can't come up with anything obvious to check.

Comment: Location 0 is suspicious because it’s often the one that gets trashed if the MCU goes loco due to bad reset hardware or configuration, wonky power supply, EMI upset or firmware issues. In general terms try disabling any WDT you have that may be hiding crashes. Try instrumenting the program and the hardware. There are a bunch of defensive programming tricks but prevention in combination with those is best. Chances are close to 100% it’s something you are doing wrong.

Comment: @KyleB
> "I would bet a month of lunches that the problem is you, not the IC"
I am inclined to agree. The problem is strange though, not like anything I've seen, and so far the vendor is perplexed as well. ESD or other environment damage could explain something like this except that the problem should be wide spread and random. Not consistently affecting just a single address. That's why I'm coming back to write endurance being the culprit even though this isn't failing the way I'd expect.

Comment: @Nick Spehro is probably right. The whole idea of address 0 just begs for the idea of software doing something that you aren't aware of, right now. But let's say that's not the problem, for now, and assume for a moment that you don't have a bug that causes excessive wear on address 0. Can you prepare a highly stripped-down assembly/machine code program that performs and demonstrates the problem? (Also, do you have an instruction trace capability with the processor core you are using?)

Comment: @jonk The EEPROM is normally turned off. We only turn it on when we need to write to it or read from it. I've instrumented the code to print to every time address 0 is written to, so I am confident in how often we write to that address, and as I said above in my question above I've identified a scenario where we could write to it an excessive number of times in production. So my question is can excessive writes begin to explain this behavior I am seeing, or should I be looking for other explanations?

Comment: @Nick The reason I asked you what I did is that I've had two separate experiences where I needed to (A) provide one manufacturer of a CPU clear, simple assembly code to demonstrate to them that 50% of their CPUs were failing to properly operate (they traced the problem to a shift from one FAB to another FAB); and, (B) provide another manufacturer of a CPU with an ICE system's trace buffer proving that the CPU was inserting instructions (NOPs that upset a specific timing requirement) and requiring a new stepping of the MCU (in a couple of months, luckily.)

Comment: @Nick So when I ask you about stripping down your code, I ***mean it***. Can you achieve that? You really need to hold their hand and carefully walk them to the problem. This means you can't have any fluff -- stuff that might confuse them. This means stripping this down to the absolute bare minimums.

Comment: @jonk I am not trying to deny that there is a software bug or defend the software. A software defect of some sort makes sense. I am trying to ask a focused question if a write endurance issue can explain this specific type of EEPROM failure mode.

I can write a stripped down firmware image to demonstrate this issue to a vendor, but doing so would certainly take me some time.

Comment: @Nick I'm not suggesting to you that there is a bug on your end. In fact, to the contrary, I'm suggesting to you that there is no bug on your side, at all. Please re-read what I wrote above. I'm asking you to assume it is "their problem" and to work out how you might prove that fact. I think if you skim back over what I wrote, you'll see that I'm not pushing you towards accepting this as your problem. I'm flipping the problem over and taking it from the exact opposite direction, instead. *"What do you need to do if this isn't your problem and you need to prove that fact to others?"*

Comment: @jonk Well, in that case, then the answer is a qualified yes. I've written code that reads and writes to this location within our bootloader, which is very limited, and observed the problem occurs in that environment. But that's only on the small set of units that already have the problem. If I run the same code on a virgin board it operates fine. So the problem tracks with this small set of units.

Comment: @Nick In my (A) case mentioned above, the problem tracked with a set of chips from a specific foundry. Have you considered this concept as it might apply in your case? Or have you excluded it, arbitrarily? But am I also picking up from you that new parts are all working okay??? If you replace an older part on one of the "bad" boards with a new part, does it start working fine?

Comment: how fast are you reading this address?  are you reading this location over and over again.  it could be read disturb, with a flash it wouldnt surprise me (been there seen that), but with an eeprom I wouldnt expect it.   otherwise this sounds like the device has been overused or a software/timing bug.

Comment: there are eeproms that can erase/change depending on how the power off (as well as power on) happens.  see if the datasheet has an comments on that and confirm

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111473/discussion-on-question-by-nick-eeprom-only-retaining-a-value-for-a-short-duratio).

Comment: Please scope the Vcc pin during a write cycle and post the result.

Comment: you would need to read rapidly to read-disturb not once every few minutes so thats not it

Comment: >>> "The power supply to the system is very stable"       .....   That is great but it's not what matters.  What matters is "is the power supply at the IC stable?"   Your series resistor may be contributing to it not being so. There are other possible reasons for it to be unstable also, like simple PCB trace impedance, other large loads nearby, etc....   See my comments in the 'chat'.  And good luck!!!

Comment: @winny I did probe the EEPROM's VCC with scope during writes. It is stable at 3V which is well within spec.

Comment: Thanks! What make and model EEPROM do you use?

Comment: I'm intentionally not mentioning the EEPROM manufacturer and part number because I have an open case with the vendor.

Comment: I see. But it’s a reputable one?

Comment: Yes, this EEPROM is from a major reputable manufacturer. Furthermore there is no suspicion of counterfeit parts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your comments you ask "if a write endurance issue can explain this specific type of EEPROM failure mode." From my past experience I would say the answer is absolutely yes.

> We have identified a situation though where we could perform a lot of writes/erases to that location in production if some steps are not performed correctly. The endurance is a million writes and we could be hitting that.

As you may know, the endurance spec of a EEPROM only applies to normal usage. If the device is written rapid-fire (for example a firmware bug causing the device to get stuck in a loop performing writes immediately one after the other) than the endurance will be much shorter. It sounds like that may be happening here.

> Previously in my career I've always seen write endurance failures look like sticking bits that seem to never take on a new value. Could this "decay" phenomenon that I am seeing also be a explained by excessive writes?

Yes. While completely "burnt" (i.e. fatigued) EEPROM cells will be stuck at a single value, it is also entirely possible for EEPROM fatigue to cause the memory operation to just degrade, rather than fail completely.

---

Footnote / war story illustrating this phenomenon:

I was on a team where we built a device with EEPROM memory storage. The customer complained that the EEPROM was failing to hold its value. They sent it back to us, we tested it and it worked fine. We sent it back to them and it failed again. This whole loop happened one more time until we visited the customer on site and found the real problem. The basic root cause:

- Customer was operating the device in a manner which caused the EEPROM to erase over and over in rapid succession, fatiguing the part. This was a surprise to us, another case where "no customer would ever do it that way" turned out to be a faulty assumption.
- Every time we tested the product at our facility we operated it "normally", so we did not see the problem.
- Here's the key: luckily we had device-level components engineers on our team, and one of those engineers informed us that *EEPROM memory cells can have a self-healing effect over time*. If you let the device rest, it will actually start to operate somewhat normally again, but obviously that device should no longer be trusted. (Note this was very surprising to me and I still don't understand the physics behind it, but all my empirical observations tell me this engineer was correct.)

So the reason this problem was so infuriatingly difficult to troubleshoot is that the EEPROM cells got fatigued by the customer to the point of failure, but then *they had a chance to rest during their time being shipped from the customer facility to ours*, so they worked fine in our testing! Then we returned them to the customer, where they would promptly get fatigued again and fail again.

Comment: Can you shed some light on or cook up a similar use that the user was doing that kept erasing the EEPROM over and over again?

Comment: @DKNguyen erase was commanded (and memory clear verified) via a discrete input and output. Internal product testing would just pulse the input and then verify successful erase on that output. The customer design would just assert the erase input and leave it asserted. The product design, for various reasons[note 1] would poll the input and erase whenever it was asserted, so leaving it asserted would cause rapid-fire erasures over and over again. [1. "Reasons" = "design flaw" or "sensible design choice for a certain set of constraints", depending on which engineer you asked.]

Comment: Oh, does erasing an erased part of memory still wear it down? I've never given it that much thought. I guess it would if it's actually trying to drive charge out whether it's there or not rather than just letting it leak out.

Comment: Great question. I don't know the answer, because in this case the "erase" was attempting to be a secure erase by writing multiple patterns to the location.